# SQL Query Optimization to retrieve non-null entries

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

Need help in optimizing SQL query, I have figured a way to solve the problem by using UNIONALL, but my worry is that performance will be impacted as the record set is huge in production env.

I have a table of records in below format, I need help in retrieving the non-null entries if available otherwise pick the null entries.

In the below case; Query should exclude RowIds 1,7 and retrieve everything else, i.e because there are non-null entries for that combination.

| RowID | UniqueID | TrackId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 325 | NULL |
| 2 | 325 | 8zUAC |
| 3 | 325 | 99XER |
| 4 | 427 | NULL |
| 5 | 632 | 2kYCV |
| 6 | 533 | NULL |
| 7 | 774 | NULL |
| 8 | 774 | 94UAC |

--UNIONALL Command

```
SELECT A.* FROM 
(  SELECT *  FROM [MY_PKG].[TEMP] WHERE TRACKID is not null) A
        WHERE A.UNIQUEID in 
        ( SELECT UNIQUEID FROM [MY_PKG].[TEMP] WHERE TRACKID is null
)
UNION ALL
SELECT B.* FROM
( SELECT * FROM [MY_PKG].[TEMP] WHERE TRACKID is null) B
        WHERE B.UNIQUEID not in 
        (  SELECT UNIQUEID FROM [MY_PKG].[TEMP] WHERE TRACKID is not null
)
```

Temp Table Creation Scrip

```
CREATE TABLE MY_PKG.TEMP
(   UNIQUEID  varchar(3),
    TRACKID   varchar(5)
);

INSERT INTO MY_PKG.TEMP
( UNIQUEID, TRACKID)
VALUES
('325',null),
('325','8zUAC'),
('325','99XER'),
('427',null),
('632','2kYCV'),
('533','2kYCV'),
('774',null),
('774','94UAC')
```

Comment: `select UNIQUEID, TRACKID
  from
  (
select *, min(TRACKID) over (partition by UNIQUEID) as mintrackid
from TEMP
  ) as t
where mintrackid is null or TRACKID is not null`

Comment: @lptr: In the example set given the `GROUP BY` will work, however I just wonder what the OP wants to see when there is also a record `9, 632, H4DcR` .. Do we need both records 5 and 9 in the output or just one? (with the lowest `TrackId` in your case)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `NOT EXISTS` operator with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM TEMP T
WHERE TRACKID IS NOT NULL
OR (TRACKID IS NULL 
    AND NOT EXISTS(
       SELECT 1 FROM TEMP D
       WHERE D.UNIQUEID = T.UNIQUEID AND 
             D.TRACKID IS NOT NULL)
   )
```

[See demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/yr9u-oLZ)